# Flutter How to load Image in cache

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem: https://streamable.com/fw7x21 . As you can see, the Images load lazy. On the first time, I think I can fix this with a Splash Screen. But when I leave the app for only 3 seconds or less, and go back in, it loads all images again from new. This look strange. Is there a way of handling this issue? I mean, my performance can't be the reason for that. I only have a Scroll View with a InkWell with an Image.asset as a child:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){},
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: ColorFiltered(
                            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), BlendMode.darken),
                            child: Image.asset("assets/widgetsImages/calc.png"),)),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "title",
                          style: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensed(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 32,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
```

I need something that safe the pictures inside the cache, so the storage can better manage to load the pictures.

Comment: even its not a netowork image?

Comment: oh sorry it's image assets.

Comment: For assets one way to create cache is to have the imageWidget as a variable inside the statefull, initializing it in the initState. With that avoid the reconstruction of the ImageProvider. [See this article](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/precache-images-in-flutter-73abfedb0769).

Comment: I tried it but it still loads the Images new when I leave the app for short time... :(